# Google Apps Script - set formula of active cell depending on value of another cell

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I’m writing a custom function in Google Apps Script that, if a certain other cell contains a number, uses the value of that cell and several other cells to calculate a result. Otherwise, if that certain other cell does not contain a number, the function should just return an empty string so that the active cell appears blank.
I was able to come up with a working function to do this, but in order to protect sensitive information, I’m not going to copy it here. Instead, here’s an example function that accomplishes the same thing:

```
function myFunction() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var rowNum = sheet.getActiveCell().getRow();
  var rowVals = sheet.getRange(rowNum, 1, 1, 15).getValues();

  var fVal = rowVals[0][5];
  if (fVal == "" || isNaN(fVal)) {
    return "";    //leave cell blank if column F doesn't contain a number
  }

  var aVal = rowVals[0][0];
  var bVal = rowVals[0][1];
  var cVal = rowVals[0][2];
  var gVal = rowVals[0][6];

  return ((gVal * fVal) + aVal + bVal + cVal);
}
```

However, in an effort to speed it up (and also some other reasons that would be complicated to try to explain here, so you'll have to just trust me), I want to have the custom function set the value of the cell to be a formula instead of doing the calculating itself. It doesn’t work to just put the formula in the cell in the first place because then it still calculates/shows a result even if column F doesn’t contain a number.
Here’s what I’ve tried so far:

```
function myFunction2() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var rowNum = sheet.getActiveCell().getRow();
  var fVal = sheet.getRange(rowNum, 6).getValue();

  if (fVal == "" || isNaN(fVal)) {
    return "";    //leave cell blank if column F doesn't contain a number
  }

  var formula = '=SUM((G2*F2)+A2+B2+C2)';

  return formula;
}
```

^This just makes the cell display the string “=SUM((G2*F2)+A2+B2+C2)”.

So I then tried using setFormula on the active cell:

```
function myFunction3() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var cell = sheet.getActiveCell();
  var rowNum = cell.getRow();
  var fVal = sheet.getRange(rowNum, 6).getValue();

  if (fVal == "" || isNaN(fVal)) {
    return "";    //leave cell blank if column F doesn't contain a number
  }

  cell.setFormula('=SUM((G2*F2)+A2+B2+C2)');
}
```

^which, when I called the function in a cell, returned an error saying “You do not have permission to call setFormula”. The same thing happened when I tried getting the a1 notation of the active cell and then using getRange(a1Notation).setFormula('=SUM((G2*F2)+A2+B2+C2)') instead of calling setFormula directly on the active cell.

Anybody know if there's a way around that permission error? or have any other ideas for how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually ended up figuring out a way to accomplish what I wanted using the built-in [IF function](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093364), so that's what I did.

Answer (score 1):

The permission error is because of restrictions on what user defined functions can do. You can, however, do this with onEdit like this:

```
function onEdit(e) {
var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
var s=ss.getActiveSheet();
var col = e.range.getColumn();
var rowNum = e.range.getRow();
if(col==6){
  var fVal = s.getRange(rowNum,col,1, 1).getValue()
 }
     if (fVal == "" || isNaN(fVal)) {
       return 
     }
      else{
        s.getRange(rowNum,col,1, 1).setFormula('=SUM((G2*F2)+A2+B2+C2)');
   }}
```

Comment: Thanks! I thought of doing something like that, but it seemed excessive/inefficient since the spreadsheet this is for gets edited quite a bit. Is using onEdit expensive, time-wise?

Comment: I have never found onEdit to be a problem. This script is limited to column F. You can further limit it to a specific sheet if you have multiple sheets. Execute the code in column F and then go to the script editor. Choose View from the menu and select Execution Transcript. It will show total run time. Mine was 0.126 seconds total runtime. Then enter something in another column. When not column F my run time is 0.002 seconds. If this answer solves your problem, please approve the answer. Thanks.